# Implicit special functions: when would they be ill-formed?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++03

In the ISO *International Standard* for C++11, a summary of the differences between c++ 2003 and C++ 2011 is given. One of the difference is:

> #### [diff.cpp03.special]
>
> **Change**: Implicitly-declared special member functions are defined as deleted when the implicit definition
> would have been ill-formed.
>
> **Rationale**: Improves template argument deduction failure.
>
> **Effect on original feature**: A valid C++ 2003 program that uses one of these special member functions in a context where the definition is not required (e.g., in an expression that is not potentially evaluated) becomes ill-formed.

I fail to see in which condition such special functions would be ill-formed, and how it could break SFINAE. So my question boils down to:

- Why such a change does *"improves template argument deduction failure"*?
- Could you give an example?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
struct NonCopyable {
  NonCopyable() {}
private:
  NonCopyable(const NonCopyable &);
};

struct S {
  NonCopyable field;
} s;

int main() {
  return sizeof S(s);
}
```

Here, `NonCopyable` is non-copyable, but as the copy constructor is explicitly provided, no implicit copy constructor is created.

For `S`, no copy constructor is provided by the user, so an implicit copy constructor is created. This copy constructor would copy the `NonCopyable` `field` field, which is non-copyable, so the copy constructor would be ill-formed.

In `main`, the size of a copy-constructed `S` object is taken. This requires a copy constructor of `S`, but doesn't actually call it.

In C++03, this is valid. The copy constructor would be ill-formed, but since no copy is ever made, it's okay.

In C++11, this is invalid. The copy constructor is marked as deleted, so cannot be used even as the operand to `sizeof`.

This allows metaprogramming to detect whether the type is copyable, which was impossible in C++03.

Comment: Do you think `<type_traits>`'s `std::is_*_constructible` do use this rule of `delete`d implicit constructors whose definition would be ill-formed?

Comment: erratum: [`std::is_*_copy_constructible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_copy_constructible)

Comment: @YSC `is_copy_constructible` just checks if `T` can be constructed from a `const T &`. If not, it doesn't care whether that's because it's implicitly deleted because its definition would be ill-formed. I don't know if that makes the answer to your question "yes" or "no".

Comment: I'd see it as a "no" then. Could you clarify your last sentence, _"This allows metaprogramming to detect whether the type is copyable, which was impossible in C++03"_? because that's the part I did not grasp entirely and made me ask.

Comment: @YSC Basically, that just means "This makes it possible to implement something like `std::is_copy_constructible` without special compiler support."

Comment: I think for this to work in 11 you'd need to use declval

Comment: so special memerfunctions will become ill,when any these will not be accessible, Only example comes into my mind when Base class constructors are private: or deleted. In in C++98 it used to give error private not accesible and in C++11 itll give Function got deleted. M i right?

Comment: @YSC is there any situation which was not an error in c++98 but itll give error in c++11?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a concrete example, std::pair is usually very easy to copy, but if one of the members is, say, a std::unique_ptr, unique_ptr doesn't allow copying from Lvalue, so it would be ill-formed: so the std::pair default Lvalue copy operations are automatically deleted.